# Generating inventory of GCP resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, terraform, gcloud, inventory

I need to generate inventory for all my `GCP` resources. For this I can go through each of the components like `VPC , Compute Engines , IAM` and generate the inventory manually . I am looking for some tool like `gcloud` or using automation software like `terraform/ansible` to generate the inventory. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Terraform and Ansible are designed for configuring infrastructure in a specific way, not for doing ad-hoc tasks like this. If all of your resources are all in Terraform state files you could potentially parse the state files to generate this but you'd be better off writing some form of script directly at the GCP API to get all of these resources directly.

Comment: Thanks . Can you please let me know which GCP API to use ?

Comment: Can I use the `Cloud Asset Inventory` feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Cloud Asset Inventory for this.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/quickstart) is a link to the quickstart guide.

My Cloud Shell was already properly configured so I only had to run:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-resources
```

Enable the API if asked when running the above command.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @Erhard Czving , to list all assets use

```
  `gcloud beta asset search-all-resources`
```

If we want to list all `VPCs` , then

```
 gcloud beta asset search-all-resources --asset-types compute.googleapis.com/Network
```

To list all `SubNetworks`

```
 gcloud beta asset search-all-resources --asset-types compute.googleapis.com/Subnetwork
```

To list all `ComputeInstances`

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-resources --asset-types compute.googleapis.com/Instance
```

To export it to `CloudStorage`

```
 gcloud beta asset export --project=<Project-ID> --output-path "gs://invent12/test"
```

List of all supported `asset-ids` can be found here

https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types

Answer (score 0):

GCP has introduced the CLI to extract details of all resources in the project. You can further customize this to get details from all projects in the organization.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/search-all-resources